# Men are treated as god for women or both treated as same according to hinduism?

Tags: scripture, women, life, men

I have listened to both of them true. but I want to know what the Hindu scriptures say about it.

Is there any scripture says that men are equivalent to god for women?

and

Is there any scripture says that men and women are treated as equal?

Comment: Unlike other religions, In Hinduism, we have male and female form of God which we all worship. So both man and woman are treated equal. There is a common saying, "Man and Woman are wheels of same vehicle, without either one, vehicle of life can't go along." :)

Comment: Please use search feature before asking the same questions over & over. There are a ton of questions on this topic already!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes mr.polai your first question is simple for purans it could be found simply:—

[Dharmic role of wife in marriage](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23203/dharmic-role-of-wife-in-marriage)

from the same question answered by ricross :—

Your second question:—

> A man, so long he does not
>   take a wife, is but (a) half
>   (incomplete) being. A half
>   (thing) can not beget. A whole
>   (thing) only can beget. This is
>   the dictum of the S'ruti.
>
> **—Vyasa Smriti 2.14**

And from my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/what-are-the-duties-of-an-ideal-husband-as-per-hinduism/23232#23232):—

> 60. In that family, where
>       the husband is pleased
>       with his wife and the
>       wife with her husband,
>       happiness will assuredly
>       be lasting.
>
> **— Book3.60:manusmriti**
>
> 55. Women must be
>       honoured and adorned
>       by their fathers,
>       brothers, husbands, and
>       brothers-in-law, who
>       desire (their own)
>       welfare.
>
> **— Book3.55:manusmriti**
>
> 56. Where women are
>       honoured, there the gods
>       are pleased; but where
>       they are not honoured,
>       no sacred rite yields
>       rewards.
>
> **— Book3.56:manusmriti**