# Qualities of a good husband?

Tags: marriage, wife, husband

We have a verse that describes the six desirable qualities of a wife:

```
“Karyeshu Daasi;Karaneshu mantri   [A servant at tasks, a minister at work]
Rupecha lakshmi; Kshamaya dharitri [Money-goddess (Lakshmi) at looks, like earth when forgiving]
Bhojyeshu mata; Sayaneshu rambha   [Mother at cooking, a nymph in bed]
Shat dharmayukta kuladharmapatni”  [That’s one’s wife, the one capable of six roles]
```

Is there a similar verse describing the virtues of a good husband?

Comment: If you are giving a quote, you should say the source.

Comment: Not necessary or mandatory to give the source here because he is not writing an answer @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the duties of an ideal husband as per Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/what-are-the-duties-of-an-ideal-husband-as-per-hinduism)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A husband should never [do](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01075.htm) anything that his wife does not like.

> No man, even in anger, should ever do anything that is disagreeable to his wife, seeing that happiness, joy, and virtue - everything dependeth on the wife.

Husband should always support his wife.

> Manusmriti 9:95. The husband receives his wife from the gods, he does not wed her according to his own will; in order to please the gods he must always support her [in every way] as long as she is faithful to him.

Husband should be loyal to his wife and protect her in any case.

> Garuda Purana 1:95:27. **A good man should be faithful to his own wife**, shall protect the female members of his family. The husband, or brother, or father, or the agnates, or the father-in-law, or the husbands’ brother of a woman, shall maintain her with food, raiments and ornaments, A woman, who is economical in her habits, simple and not extravagant in her toilette, cleanly and ingenious in her household works, and is of a cheerful temperament, should be maintained by her friends (relations, Vandhus).

> Manusmriti 9:7. He who carefully guards his wife, preserves (the purity of) his offspring, virtuous conduct, his family, himself, and his (means of acquiring) merit.